# I want to make a discord music bot in js

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, bots, discord

I want a music bot that's running by Heroku & GitHub(0-24 host).

But when I type in `index.js const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');` the bot stops working. I installed ytdl-core (`npm i ytdl-core`).

Code :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

const fs = require("fs");

const PREFIX = '+';

const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
```

[Full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGtMz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you use `ytdl()` but need for  `new ytdl()` and generally if you use from ytdl only `discord` why not require `ytdl-core-discord`

It will work

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
...
let newDiscord =  new ytdl (...[]);
```

And finally I recommend you use like that

```
const ytdlDiscord = require('ytdl-core-discord');
...
let newDiscord =  new ytdlDiscord (...[]);
```

Comment: Can u describe it more precisely that ' let newDiscord =  new ytdl (...[]); ' ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGtMz.png 
There when you defined a const dispatcher used constructor without a **new** Keyword

Comment: My answer for you can see ```ytdl``` using way